# Adding a script for search functionality in the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a script for the search filter and having an error in implementing it. Please let me know where I am wrong

I have added the search bar using the code

```
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for the courses">
```

and after that I added the script inside the body tag

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable h4").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="my-4">
  <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Open Academy</h1>
</header>

<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for the courses">

<div class="row text-center" id="myTable">



  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Deep Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course to Deep learning </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Machine Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course by Cognitive Classes on Machine Learning.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Why are you trying to replicate ctrl-f? And why not use fragment identifiers and links?

Comment: When I am searching in the search bar It's not filtering the cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show something higher than what you are currently finding.

You cannot hide the cards and then try to show the H4 inside the card.
Access `$("#myTable .card")` instead

Also you abuse a side effect of filter - Either filter on content or toggle on content

If the wrapping div is not hidden, you will get a scattering. So now I toggle the hidden wrapper instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable .card").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().toggle(
        $.trim(value)!="" && $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
      )
   });   
  });
});
```

```css
#myTable>div { display:none; float:left; border:1px solid grey; margin:5px; padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="my-4">
  <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Open Academy</h1>
</header>

<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for the courses">

<div class="row text-center" id="myTable">



  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Deep Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course to Deep learning </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Machine Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course by Cognitive Classes on Machine Learning.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Deep Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course to Deep learning </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Machine Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course by Cognitive Classes on Machine Learning.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Deep Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course to Deep learning </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Machine Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course by Cognitive Classes on Machine Learning.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Deep Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course to Deep learning </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Machine Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course by Cognitive Classes on Machine Learning.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Deep Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course to Deep learning </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Machine Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course by Cognitive Classes on Machine Learning.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I understand.

Comment: On writing the edited script provided by you. It's just hiding the cards that don't match the query and showing the resulted cards at the same position. I also want the searched results to shows on top

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: If we are having 50+ cards places in 5 x 10 matrix , then on implementing this script, when we searched in the search bar it just hide the unmatched query and rest of the cards do not change their position. I want the matched query cards to show on the top. Right now they are placed in the scrattered form

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling the `h4` instead of the `.card` that contains it.
You also do not need to toggle while filtering. Filter the ones you want and show them in one go. If you want to go one-by-one then use the `.each` instead of the `.filter`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var allCards = $('#myTable .card');

    allCards
      .hide() // hide all cards
      .filter(function() { // filter the cards that match
        var h4text = $(this).find('h4').text().toLowerCase();
        return h4text.indexOf(value) > -1;
      }).show() // show the filtered cards

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="my-4">
  <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Open Academy</h1>
</header>

<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for the courses">

<div class="row text-center" id="myTable">



  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Deep Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course to Deep learning </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Machine Learning</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is an introductory course by Cognitive Classes on Machine Learning.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```